# RegEx to find Windows file paths inside of text

Tags: c#, regex

I have been bashing my head against this one for a few hours and I just can't seem to crack it.

I have been tasked with writing an application that loops through numerous config files to identify any valid windows file or folder paths within the text.

eg:

```
\\\10.0.0.1\folder\
\\\10.0.0.1\folder\filename.txt

\\\servername\folder\
\\\servername\folder\filename.txt

d:\folder\
d:\folder\filename.txt
```

I am using C# and here is the closest working version I've got so far

```
string ex = @"(?!.*[\\\/]\s+)(?!(?:.*\s|.*\.|\W+)$)(?:[a-zA-Z]:)?(?:(?:[^<>:\|\?\*\n])+(?:\/\/|\/|\\\\|\\)?)+$";
var rx = new Regex(ex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var matches = rx.Matches(output);
                        
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
```

You can see work in progress [here](https://regex101.com/r/T8vZNl/72)

It does exactly what I need with the "`d:\`" paths but those start with "`\\\\`" it only kind of works if that path is at the start of the string?!?

Ideally if I could just get the Folder paths returned excluding the file that would be an added bonus.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try this regex: https://regex101.com/r/T8vZNl/73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to capture folder and filename in 2 separate capture groups:

```
(?:\\\\[^\\]+|[a-zA-Z]:)((?:\\[^\\]+)+\\)?([^<>:]*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T8vZNl/73)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:\\\\[^\\]+|[a-zA-Z]:)`: Match either a server name or IP address that starts with `\\` followed by 1+ non-`\` characters OR a drive letter followed by a `:` in a non-capturing group
- `((?:\\[^\\]+)+\\)?`: 1st capture group for folder path that matches a string starting with a `\` and matches 1+ non-`\` characters allowing multiple occurrences of that followed by a `\`. This group is optional due to presence of `?` in the end.
- `([^<>:]*)`: Match filename that 0 or more of any character that is not `<`, `>` and `:`